# How to integrate aws-xray in fast api?

Tags: fastapi, aws-xray

I am working with [fast api](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

I would like to integrate x-ray but could not find any example on line, I can see there is a feature request but I also found [this github answer](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/issues/270)
where it states `You can now instruments your FastAPI application using Open Telemetry Python SDK and sends data to X-Ray service.`

But could only find flask\django examples.

Does anyone have a short example\link ?

would really appreciate it!

THX!